# Cyclotomic polynomials to find the subgroups of a Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

> With $f(x) = x^{10}+1$, I want to draw the lattice of subgroups of the group $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$.

Using cyclotomic polynomials I find that we have the $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{20}}) / \mathbb{Q})$ which has $8$ elements in it. I am thinking there are $5$ subgroups of these elements. Is that right? What would the lattice look like then?

Comment: I believe this is a subextension of the splitting field of $x^{20}-1$, so the Galois group must be a subgroup of $(\mathbb Z/20\mathbb Z)^\times\cong(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times\times(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^\times$. Can you find the appropriate (I think normal, since this extension is Galois) subgroup there?